# Expand All on default RadGridView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm using `Telerik:RadGridView` in my `WPF` application. This is a nested grid which has child grid. Now on default load i should expand all the rows. I tried few things but not working.

//Code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdExpan" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  AutoExpandGroups="True" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8"  Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ClipboardPasteMode="None" ShowGroupPanel="False" ItemsSource="{Binding SList, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource CopyViewModel}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  RowHeight="30" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" CanUserReorderColumns="False" AlternationCount="2" IsFilteringAllowed="False" >
```

Tried `AutoExpandGroups="True"` and in code behind tried in constructor

```
 public CopyWindow()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     grdExpan.ExpandAllHierarchyItems();
  }
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling the `ExpandAllHierarchyItems` method in the Loaded event of your window, or alternatively check this forum thread out: [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/expandallhierarchyitems-in-three-level-hierarchy)